# Check if Windows 7 product key has been used

Tags: windows-7, windows, product-key

Selling my Windows 7 as used to someone, however, I have lost track of whether the product key is still used on an old PC of mine.

Is there any quick way to check whether a product key has been used or not? (Without going through the install and activation process).

N.B: It's all a legitimate purchase from Microsoft!

**EDIT**: I have found a piece of software which checks if the product key is valid, but not sure if the information displayed shows if the product key is already activated (refer to screenshot section on the link)... The link to the software I found is at http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Windows-7-Product-Key-Checker.shtml

Comment: To clarify my comment the purpose of doing this is to verify which key has been activated on the PCM in question

Comment: since you asked about not having to go through the activation process again. Determining the key that is stored on the laptop, and then doing the same on other machines you have seems like a valid way to figure it out. Presumably you did activate this key before and are just verifying it won't accidentally be used again by the other machine. Keyfinder has a free version and I have used it to reinstall windows on a new drive for the same machine, so I know it works

Comment: It would be wise to not enter your product key into a 3rd party website...

Answer (score 3):

- Go to *Control Panel*
- Click *System and Security*
- Click *System*
- In the bottom-right corner click *Change Product Key*
- This verifies the key without having to start a Windows installation

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this wouldn't show whether it is on another machine though. It would have to then go through activation, which in turn would activate the product key in question!

I have found a piece of software that may work, see my edit for details

Comment: This procedure will check if the key is valid, not if it's being used (or actually it will - after these steps it's used at least once, but that's not what OP asked for).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a utility like

http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

on your machines and compare them.

Unless you mean it may be used elsewhere and you have no idea where

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for the input, I haven't got a clue where the product key could be (if anywhere, I build computers). I guess the best bet would be to phone Microsoft and check?

Comment: try keyfinder will just find it

Comment: The suggested application I have does NOT display the valid key AND costs money.

Comment: no idea about the application you have, but keyfinder has a free version and works fine